# Bin Packing Truck Load Optimization using Ms Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Currently were doing the truck load optimization plan manually and it takes a lot of time to finish the plan specially during peak season. My initiative is to automate the plan using excel macro in order to save time and can focus on other given tasks. I've been searching in internet these past few days but unfortunately I'm not able to find any solution related to ms excel.

Below is the scenario of my problem.

First snapshot is the list of the products and its configuration is pieces/box.
Second snapshot is the sample orders of the products and its equivalent boxes.

The constraint is each truck can load only up to 1,000 boxes and the maximum weight is 5,000kg. Any products can be combined to load the truck as long as not exceeding the maximum limit.

Third snapshot is the expected result based on the given constraint.

Appreciate your help on how to do this load optimization using ms excel vba. Thanks in Advance!

[image: **product configuration**]

[image: List of orders]

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: You get that this is a well known maths game with many answers don't you?

Comment: I would suggest doing some research on VBA and narrowing your question down to be more specific instead of open-ended. Here's one of the tutorials I used when I was first learning VBA https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/

Comment: @ Jeeped - I know it's not a simple problem. I've been searching the internet but not able to find any solution using ms excel.

Comment: this is not an Excel or VBA question, you are asking us to figure out the mathematical modeling of this optimization, you need to figure it out first and then try to write it in Excel or VBA

Comment: Its not difficult just tell me the capacity of each truck?

Comment: The capacity of the truck can load maximum 1,000 boxes with the weight of maximum 5,000kg.

Comment: First, your math for carton D is wrong. 500 boxes @ 6kg each is not 5000kg. This means your load calculations are also wrong. Second, Custom software is available to run this sort of scenario. I used TOPS for close to 20 years and it works great. Your problem may not be one of writing code but maybe writing a better ROI. It wouldn't take many miscalculated trucks like the one above to pay for the software. If, however, MS Excel is your ONLY option, it's necessary to know if all boxes are the same size.