# Creating a graph in Excel based on Cubic measurements on a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have an excel document that i am using to calculate the amount of space i can utilize in a shipping container. I have the measurements of the shipping container and a table where i will enter each box that i want to load into it (for example's sake i only put 15 lines). I want to fill the rectangles at the top which are supposed to represent the shipping container, based on the values entered in the table. does anyone know how i could go about this?

i'm not sure if i should make the rectangles bigger, or if there is a graph template that can be used

Comment: Search for "bun packing”, a classic problem, also look on here. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/51562891/4961700

Comment: Are the tables “flat packed" or do the legs waste space? Do the tables stack?